# Passing a variable between classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, oop, variables

I am trying to pass a variable "budget" from my DocumentClass of a flash file, to a class.

Currently I have :

(DocumentClassv5 , this is the code thats attached to the flash file in the properties panel, some code ommited)

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;    
import miniGameOne;
import floorTileMC;


import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;



public class DocumentClassv5 extends MovieClip 
{
    /*#################################
    ## Defining Variables            ##
    #################################*/

    public var budget:int = 0;

    var gameOne:miniGameOne = new miniGameOne();
        /*#################################
    ## Constructor                   ##
    #################################*/     
    public function DocumentClassv5() 
    {
        /*#################################
        ## Adding Event Listeners        ##
        #################################*/


        trace("Document class loaded");
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*###################################################
    ## Begins the mini game                            ##
    ###################################################*/           
    public function begin(evt: MouseEvent)
    {
        beginGame.visible = false;
        beginGame.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, begin);
        budget = 500;

        cleanListeners();
        gameOne.loadGame();
        trace(gameOne.testVar);
        trace(floorTile.testVar2);

        /*#################################
        ## Adding Event Listeners        ##
        #################################*/         


        trace("Game started");
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
}
```

Then I have the miniGameOne class file, which at the moment does nothing

I also have another class file, called tileFloorMC. This is attached to a symbol.

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import DocumentClassv5;


public class floorTileMC extends MovieClip 
{
    var propertyA:Number;
    //var hackerClass:DocumentClassv5 = new DocumentClassv5;
            public var testVar2:int = 50;

    public function floorTileMC() 
    {
        this.propertyA = randomRange(100, 500);

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, manageMouseOut, false, 0, true);
    }
    private function manageMouseOver(evt: MouseEvent)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
        //trace(mainClass.budget);
    }
    private function manageMouseOut(evt: MouseEvent)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
        //mainClass.budget += 1;
    }
    private function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number   
    {  
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);  
    }       

}

}
```

Now, essentially I will need to be able to pass budget from DocumentClassv5 TO floorTileMC, and then BACK to DocumentClassv5. At the moment, I can pass anything from floorTileMC and anything from miniGameOne into DocumentClassv5, but when i try and pass from floorTileMC to DocumentClassv5, I get error 
Error #2136: The SWF file file:///yadayada/GameV5.swf contains invalid data.

More specifically, as soon as I uncomment //var hackerClass:DocumentClassv5 = new DocumentClassv5;

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Tiffany

Comment: No they are not in different SWF's, there is only One SWF. And I don't know of any other way to pass variables between classes, is there?

Comment: Essentially I am going to need all 3 classes to talk to each other a lot, passing back and forth information, I thought this was the only way to do it ?

Comment: in regards to budgetInfo,  if it only exists on frame 7, then it isn't instantiated until the play head reaches frame 7.   Your getting a compiler error because it doesn't know it exists.  Put this in the class who has budgetInfo on it's timeline:   `public var budgetInfo:TextField;`.

Comment: make sure it's a not a typo.  Everything is case sensitive. I put the 'i' in info as a capital, you have it as lower case (not sure if you just copy and pasted or not).

Comment: Negative on the typo, not sure why its doing it :9

Comment: And again, I do really reallly realllllly appreciate your help, im already further along than i hoped to be at this point because of your awesomeness :)

Comment: I can tell you it has nothing to do with the stuff your question was about.  If you post your .fla somewhere it would be easy to find the issue.  This is starting to turn into a discussion though, and stackoverflow is more for specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate your document class in a subclass:

```
var hackerClass:DocumentClassv5 = new DocumentClassv5();
```

You want access to access the existing instance, not create a new one.

One thing you can do, is create a static reference to your document class. (see code sample below)

Static references can get ugly though, and you may just want to pass a reference of your doc class to your other classes when you instantiate them.

Both method below:

In your document class:

```
//instead of the line below:
var gameOne:miniGameOne = new miniGameOne(); //It's a bad idea to instantiate non primitive objects before the constructor of your document class runs.

//just declare it, and instantiate it in the constructor
var gameOne:miniGameOne;

//if you want to use a static reference:
public static var me:DocumentClassv5;

public function DocumentClassv5() 
{
    /*#################################
    ## Adding Event Listeners        ##
    #################################*/

    //if using the static var me, set it's value to this (the instance of the document class):
    me = this;


    trace("Document class loaded");
    gameOne = new miniGameOne(this); //pass a reference to the document class if NOT using the static var me


}
```

If using the static var me, you access it by doing the following from any class:

```
DocumentClassV5.me.budget;
```

Another cleaner alternative (if the values you need access to aren't really directly tied to any class, eg. global preferences), is make a whole new class that is just static (doesn't get instantiated) to hold your preferences.

```
package {
    public class Global {

        public static var budget:Number = 50;

    }
}
```

Then you'd access budget by importing your Global class and doing `Global.budget = 5`

Comment: Alright, that is allowing me to pull information FROM DocumentClassv5 and bring it into my floorTileMC class, which is great. How would I call a function from the DocumentClass though? I added in a new function called testingFunction which just does a trace("called"), and tried to call it using DocumentClassv5.me.testingFunction but it threw me an error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: floorTileMC is a symbol's class file, and the symbol is placed on the stage which is instantiating it.

Comment: What do you mean pass a reference to the document class? Sorry, I'm still learning AS in general >.< And I REALLY appreciate all the help your giving!

Comment: OK, so when you do new miniGameOne(this) you are GIVING miniGameOne a copy of the DocumentClassv5 , so DocumentClassv5 will no longer need to be a static reference?

Comment: In regards to your error, make sure you declare your function as public.

Comment: miniGameOne(this) is passing a reference to the constructor of the miniGameOne class. So then you could just have a var in that class (miniGameOne) that references the document class INSTEAD of using the static var.

Comment: Probably have a typo then,  update your question and post the code your using (both the document class and where you're calling the testingFunction

Comment: I don't even know if this is practicle or useful, should I just code two games in one document class? would that be easier, honestly? Like I said, I am new to this sort of coding, and feel like im pulling my hair out of my head trying to figure it out.

Comment: For things like preferences, Static variables can work well.  You want to separate all your logically processes into different class files or your document class will big and ugly and hard to manage. I see you updated the document class, but I don't the see testFunction anywhere?